# Matlab fitrensemble capped to 99 observations

Tags: matlab, regression

Probably, a very simple fix, but I've been trying to run random forest algo on some data using the built-in `fitrensemble` method.

I pass in a 2D matrix X with the training data, and the vector output as Y.

These matrices have 3499 rows each. X has 6 columns and Y 1.

Yet, I get the following output from my fitrensemble call:

```
         ResponseName: 'Y'
CategoricalPredictors: []
    ResponseTransform: 'none'
      NumObservations: 99
           NumTrained: 100
               Method: 'LSBoost'
         LearnerNames: {'Tree'}
 ReasonForTermination: 'Terminated normally after completing the requested number of training cycles.'
              FitInfo: []
   FitInfoDescription: 'None'
       Regularization: []
            FResample: 1
              Replace: 1
     UseObsForLearner: [99×100 logical]
```

`NumObservations` is always capped at 99... why is that? Note that when I reduce the size of the training data to have less than 99 rows, then the value of 'NumObservations` comes down to match it. I tried setting it as an argument but that didn't work either.

Comment: Show a [mcve] please

Comment: It probably has to do with the nature of your data, actually

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri. What do you have in mind when you say "nature of the data" ? I've done a quick back of the envelop calculation based on the number of variables I have and the expected shape of the relationships (i.e. how many samples per dimensions) and I got an estimate of about 2000 samples to correctly explore my parameter space. That's why I'm surprised with the limit at 99 which seems imposed by Matlab.

Comment: The limit is not imposed by MATLAB. If I use the code in the examples of the function docs (but `load carbig` isntead of `load carsmall`) I get over 300 NumSamples used. So, what I mean is exactly what you said: possibly you don't need 2000 samples, just 99 are enough.

Comment: Ok, but that seems strange to me as a lot of the parameter space will be left unexplored with only 99 samples. That means the model will perform poorly if interrogated on those areas. I'd be curious to see how that number is determined by the Matlab code.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what that numbers refers to actually, maybe its not what you think it is. Maybe it tested more, and then realized that more overfits?

Comment: Okay, so to test that I've added a line to randomly shuffle my dataset prior to training and yes, the value of selected observations fluctuates. That's interesting - but confusing at the same time. The only way I can explain it is if most of my parameters have very little influence on the output. :/

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have much experience with the function, so take what I say with a grain of salt. I mostly wanted to point out that MATLAB is not setting this limit, but calculating it Maybe showing a [mcve] will help

Comment: I think you're right. I get that you were just pointing that it was a calculated value - not a fixed one. But now I can see that my parameter space shouldn't be sampled linearly. I am looking at a heat transfer problem with a finite amount of heat - so if I use linear sampling I end up with a lot of my samples looking at the problem after it has equilibrated ... hence why all the outputs are very similar.